# Compare 2 dataframe columns and delete rows

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, string-comparison, data-processing

I have 2 `dataframes` with different lengths. I would like to compare and delete unavailable values(`rows`) from df1.

Here is an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Filename':['image1','image1','image2','image3'], 
                    'Name':['Dog','Cat','Cat', 'Cat'],
                     'values':['2','3','4','5']  })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Filename':['image1','image2','image3'], 
                    'Name':['Dog','Cat', 'Cat'],
                     'values':['5','6','7']  })
```

`df1`

```
Filename    Name    values

0   image1  Dog 2

1   image1  Cat 3

2   image2  Cat 4

3   image3  Cat 5
```

`df2`

```
Filename    Name    values

0   image1  Dog 5

1   image2  Cat 6

2   image3  Cat 7
```

I'm expecting 2 dataframes(df1 and df2) with same length and with same `Filename` and `Name` as below. My goal is to compare the `values` column of `df1` and `df2` with same `Filename` and `Name`.

`df1`

```
Filename    Name    values

0   image1  Dog 2

2   image2  Cat 4

3   image3  Cat 5
```

`df2`

```
Filename    Name    values

0   image1  Dog 5

1   image2  Cat 6

2   image3  Cat 7
```

I have tried comparing each row with corresponding df and delete if not available. (This is clearly not the way to do)

```
for i, j in df1.iterrows():
    for m, n in df1.iterrows():
        if m['Filename'] == i['Filename']:
            if m['LabelName'] == i['LabelName']:
                pass
            else:
                print('delete')
                df2=df2.drop(i)
                df1=df1.sort_values('Filename')
                df2=df2.sort_values('Filename')
                
            break
```

I also tried to implement groupby and compare with rows and i encountered `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects` since indexes won't be same.

Can someone please help me with this? I tried searching for similar problems but did not come across any.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: ++Added more description

Comment: you should use [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Something like `df1.merge(df2, on=['Filename', 'Name'], how='inner')` should work. However, your question is surely a duplicate, you could have found the answer elsewhere :)

Comment: I'm feeling stupid. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A solution not so pythonic, however it does the work:

```
l1=[(df1.Filename.iloc[i],df1.Name.iloc[i]) for i in range(len(df1))]
l2=[(df2.Filename.iloc[i],df2.Name.iloc[i]) for i in range(len(df2))]
lfin=[i for i in l1 if i in l2]
   
for i in df1.index:
    if (df1.Filename.loc[i], df1.Name.loc[i]) not in lfin:
        df1.drop(i, inplace=True)

for i in df2.index:
    if (df2.Filename.loc[i], df2.Name.loc[i]) not in lfin:
        df2.drop(i, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

hey i think this work pretty well

```
df3 = df2.set_index('Filename')
df1[df1.apply(lambda x : df3.loc[x.Filename]['Name']== x.Name , axis =1 ) ]
```

and if you want to lose the index and reset it you can add

```
df3 = df2.set_index('Filename')
df1[df1.apply(lambda x : df3.loc[x.Filename]['Name']== x.Name , axis =1 )  ].reset_index().drop('index' , axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Amine. I guess i found my answer in comments section